# Google analytics segments - total events for a specific event

Tags: google-analytics

I need to create a segment that needs conditions such as:

1. Sign up event occurred
2. Login event occurred
3. Event with action 'Test' occured 3 times

However, I could not find any way to do this. There is a condition called "Total events", but it seems to apply for all types of events not for a specific one.

Is there any way of doing this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If everything else fails you could create a sequence type segment and set the same event category/action/label as condition for each step.

Comment: Ok, this is one way to go but will it work if another event occurs in between step 2 and 3? For example,

1. Sign up event occurred
2. Login event occurred
3. 'Test2' event occurred
4. Event with action 'Test' occured 3 times